# Sublime 2 sidebar folders not working in Ubuntu 13

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext2, ubuntu-13.10

Been using ST2 for a while in Windows and now that I got Ubuntu 13.10 I ran it with no problems. It lets me add folders just fine and they work perfectly, hierarchies and all. But on reboot, sublime will open like always, with the folders in there, but no files "exist" and the sidebar's folders are empty.

The folders all point to a folder in the /media folder if that's of any use. Outside of that, there is nothing out of the ordinary.

I'm expecting there to be something big I'm missing, like "Ubuntu fails to load things on boot because the file system takes a while to respond" or "this is a known error, just change the default config file in sublime".

Comment: Upon reboot, look in the target folder in `/media` and see if it exists, and if the files are there. Typically, `/media` is for resources that are mounted on demand, like CD drives, network shares, etc. You may not have automount configured correctly.

Comment: That's what I thought originally but they do in fact exist. That's what I end up doing: I notice sublime isn't recognizing them so I, literally, right click on the "useless" folder and make it open the target folder and it opens the correct one. So I go on to remove it from Sublime, then redragging it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the comments by MattDMo were right. Sublime text 2 (maybe 3) will not load project folders correctly if the files are on a mounted drive. Even with auto-mounting scripts it will require a refresh. I ended up simply moving the files over to my /home directory. Not the best solution but it seems like this is the intended use.